# The series $\sum a_n$ is conditionally convergent. Prove that the series $\sum n^2 a_n$ is divergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Ratio and root tests won't help. And I can't use the comparison test because $ |a_n| $ is not necessarily smaller than $ n^2a_n $.

Can I use limits? We know:

1. $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0 $
2. $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} |a_n| \ne 0 $

And we need to prove:

1. $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^2a_n \ne 0 $

Any ideas/hints?

Comment: Your second point is incorrect: since $\lim a_n=0$, we have $\lim|a_n|=0$ too.  And we don't **have** to prove $\lim n^2a_n\ne0$: this would be sufficient but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose that $n^2 a_n$ had a convergent series: That is,

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^2 a_n = \ell \in \mathbb{R}$$

Then $n^2 a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, so $n^2 a_n$ is eventually less than $1$ in absolute value, implying that $$|a_n| < \frac 1 {n^2}$$

for sufficiently large $n$. Now think about the comparison test.

Comment: Then I take the limit of both sides. The limit of $|a_n|$ =/=. Since we're taking the absolute value, it will be greater than 0. The limit of $ 1/n^2$ = 0. LS greater than 0 cannot be less than 0, so there is a contradiction. Correct?

Comment: Just knowing that the limit of $1/n^2$ is zero isn't enough (consider the limit $1/n$, for example). Just compare directly to the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} 1/n^2$.

Comment: What am I comparing to the series $1/n^2$? The sum of the series $n^2a_n$ ? But if it's less than $1/n^2$, and $1/n^2$ is convergent, that tells me $n^2a_n$ is convergent, which is the wrong answer. I'm very confused.

Comment: If we were to suppose that $\sum n^2 a_n$ is convergent, then compare $\sum |a_n|$ to $\sum 1/n^2$. From the above scratchwork, we'll find that $\sum |a_n|$ converges, which is quite bad.

Comment: Ohhhh I see. Thank you.